# preprocess center and scale produces an error

Tags: r

From caret Package

I have a vector

```
library(caret)
A<-c(-1,1-1,3,2,-2,-1,5,2,3,-3)
```

I would like to preprocess center and scale the above vector, have tried as a vector, data.frame and a matrix. Would like doing it using the preprocess function not manually taking the mean end substracting it from the data etc. Am I missing something?

```
#preProcess(A, method = c("center", "scale"))
#Error en apply(x, 2, mean, na.rm = na.remove) : 
#dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data frame works

```
library(caret)
test <- preProcess(data.frame(A = c(-1,1-1,3,2,-2,-1,5,2,3,-3)))
predict(test, data.frame(A = c(-1,1-1,3,2,-2,-1,5,2,3,-3)))
#            A
#1  -0.6994725
#2  -0.3108767
#3   0.8549108
#4   0.4663150
#5  -1.0880683
#6  -0.6994725
#7   1.6321024
#8   0.4663150
#9   0.8549108
#10 -1.4766641
```